# Returing Hystrix AsyncResult from Spring Boot Controller

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I have the following Spring Boot controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService service;


    @GetMapping(path="/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleGet() {
        return service.getResponse();
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/hello/hystrix")
    public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> handleGetAsync() {
        return service.getResponseAsync();
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/hello/cf")
    public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> handleGetCF() {
        return service.getResponseCF();
    }
}
```

and service:

```
@Service
public class TestService {
    @HystrixCommand
    public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello");
        return response;
    }

    @HystrixCommand
    public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> getResponseAsync() {
        return new AsyncResult<ResponseEntity<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ResponseEntity<String> invoke() {
                return getResponse();
            }
        };
    }

    public Future<ResponseEntity<String>> getResponseCF() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getResponse());
    }
}
```

and application:

```
@EnableHystrix
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class HystrixApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HystrixApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I hit the /hello/cf endpoint, I get a response "Hello"
When I hit the /hello/hystrix endpoint, I get a 404 error.

Am I able to return an AsyncResult from a controller in this manner?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Exact code gives me `{
cancelled: false,
done: true
}`. I don't see 404

Answer (score -1):

Your service class needs to return a CompletableFuture.

Also, unless you are using AspectJ, the circuit breaker will not work if the method with @HystrixCommand is called from within the same class.